# require solution for string replacement

Tags: ruby

I have a code where I have to replace a string with another string.

My file contains

```
secondaryPort = 7504
```

The code below

```
filtered_data =
  filtered_data.gsub(
    /secondaryPort=\d+/,
    'secondaryPort=' + node['server']['secondaryPort']
  )
```

should replace my file with

```
secondaryPort = 7555
```

but it fails to do so.

Comment: Seems like there's whitespace around `=` but not in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you account for the spaces around the equals sign in your string:

```
filtered_data = 'secondaryPort = 7504'
=> 'secondaryPort = 7504'

# with literal spaces
filtered_data.gsub(/secondaryPort = \d+/, 'secondaryPort = 7555')
=> 'secondaryPort = 7555'

# with regex character class for literal space
filtered_data.gsub(/secondaryPort\s{1}=\s{1}\d+/, 'secondaryPort = 7555')
=> 'secondaryPort = 7555'
```

Comment: It may be worth clarifying that `\s` in Ruby is [equivalent to](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) `[ \t\r\n\f\v]`.

Comment: @Jordan, that's a very nice way of explaining it. I just need an mnemonic device to remember it.

Comment: Alternatively: `filtered_data[/secondaryPort\s*=\s*(\d+)/, 1] = '7555'` assuming that there's at most one match in the string.